# Trouble putting a local SVN repo on SourceForge

Tags: svn, version-control, repository, hosting, sourceforge

I have a local SVN repo.  Let's say it's in `c:\Game Repo`.  This contains both code and content (art, models, etc), and we need both tracked with source control.

I'd like to upload that to a hosting platform.  SourceForge *seems* like the best option (although I'm not trying to start a debate on that), but their site has a near-non-existent help section.  There doesn't seem to be an obvious way to "push" the repo (so to speak) or set the remote, as one would do with git / github.

The SourceForge project has a "code" section, which is an empty subversion repository.  There are (brief) instructions for "Import project on disk to Subversion":

```
cd existing-game-repo-code
svn import svn+ssh://game-repo@svn.code.sf.net/p/game-repo/code/ -m "Initial commit"
```

However, I get these errors:

```
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn+ssh://game-repo@svn.code.sf.net/p/game-repo/code'
svn: E210002: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: E210002: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Under the Admin section, there's an import repo tool.  However, they very specifically want a URL as input.  I tried using

```
file:///C:/Game Repo
```

No dice.  "That is not a valid URL."

If I *had* a URL, I wouldn't be on SourceForce.  I'm trying to *get* the URL.

**Update:**

Trying `svn import svn://game-repo@svn.code.sf.net/p/game-repo/code/ -m "Initial commit"` results in `svn: E170001: Authorization failed`, even though I'm certain I have the correct username and password.

Using `svn import https://game-repo@svn.code.sf.net/p/game-repo/code/ -m "Initial commit"` gives me:

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://svn.code.sf.net:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? t
svn: E170013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://game-repo@svn.code.sf.net/p/game-repo/code'
svn: E120108: Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection.
```

Comment: There is no concept of _pushing_ in svn as it exists in git because in svn there is _a single repo_ against which you (and every else) works. If you have a local svn repo (as you say you do have) then _that_ is the repo.... if you would like to move it around (say, put it in another server), then you need to export it end import it into the other server. Can that be done in sourceforce? I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to import local files into a new repository, use the `svn import` command as follows:

```
cd existing-game-repo-code
svn import URL-TO-REPOSITORY/trunk -m "Initial commit"
```

So the command you are running is correct. Perhaps there is some problem with SourceForge that prevents you from using the svn+ssh:// URL.

Have you tried the `svn://` URL? I mean without the `+ssh` part. And try the `https://` URL, too.

PS Do yourself a favour and try another hosted Subversion repo service. Or deploy your own Subversion server installation locally or in the cloud.

Comment: Ok.  I've tried those two suggestions and added my results to the original question.